# Closure of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Consider the set $A=\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3):a_i\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Determine the closure of $A$ [$cl(A)$].

My approach:

Since it is known that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\subseteq cl(\mathbb{Q})$, which implies that $cl(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is only a subset of itself (since we only consider real numbers).
Thus $\mathbb{R}$, being the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, is a closet set, which implies that $\mathbb{R}$ contains all limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $\forall a_i\in A$, $\exists$ a sequence $a_{n_i}\to a_i$ as $n\to \infty$, which implies that the sequence $\vec{a}_n:=(a_{n_1},a_{n_2,}a_{n_3})\to \vec{a}\in\mathbb{R^3}$. Hence, the closure of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'd appreciate your opinion on this - is this a correct approach?

Comment: nitpick: closure only makes sense for a subset of another topological space, so the question should specify what $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ is being considered a subset of (I assumed $\mathbb R^3$?)

Comment: The question doesn't specify that, but I'm pretty sure it's $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Your approach has the right idea. You want to show an arbitrary point in $\mathbb R^3$ is a limit point of $A$, so instead of $\forall a_i\in A$ I think you want $\forall(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $X\times Y$ is given the product topology, I believe it's true that for any $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$, the closure of $A\times B$ in $X\times Y$ is simply $\bar A\times\bar B$. That reduces this problem to just knowing that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. (Of course there are plenty of sets in $X\times Y$ besides sets of the form $A\times B$ ... but for those special sets, nothing surprising happens.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're assuming the metric $d(r,q)=|r_1-q_1|+|r_2-q_2|+|r_3-q_3|$ in $\mathbb{Q}^3$ (or an equivalent one), and that you know that the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the usual metric) is $\mathbb{R}$.

You're trying to show that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}^3}=\mathbb{R}^3$. Pick any $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. As the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(t^x_n)_n$ such that $|x-t^x_n|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. The same reasoning applies with $y$ and $z$, leading to $$d((x,y,z),(t^x_n,t^y_n,t^z_n))=|x-t^x_n|+|y-t^y_n|+|z-t^z_n|\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$; i.e. $(x,y,z)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}^3}$ proving your claim by the arbitrariness of $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: It almost looks like you rephrased my proof :)

Comment: @sequence Look at what you wrote carefully; what you're proving (sketching to be accurate) is that $\mathbb{Q}^3\subset\overline{\mathbb{Q}^3}$, which is trivially true.